# How to use GCP Cloud Build caching when deploying to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

GCP Cloud Build [can use cached image](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image) to speed up builds.

I'm currently deploying to a Cloud Run service with `gcloud run deploy zero2prod --source=.`, and noticed that Cloud Build under the hood doesn't utilize caching. What is the ideal way to make it use cached images?

Comment: What do you want to cache? Your code? the libraries? the base images? the intermediary layers?*

Comment: Intermediary layers. Some of these layers are responsible to cache dependencies, code compilation, etc. I want to speed up builds this way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `--cache-from` flag when you build the image. The `--cache-from` option need to be supplied in `cloudbuild.yaml` file.

This may not be the ideal way, but you could follow this for caching,

Step 1 : In the `cloudbuild.yaml` file and use `--cache-from` during the build.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker pull 
         gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest || exit 0']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
        'build',
        '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
        '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
        '.'
    ]
  images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest']
```

Step 2: Build this

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

Step 3: Deploy to cloud run

```
# gcloud run deploy zero2prod --image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Kaniko executor](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/kaniko-cache) in my Cloud Build step, like this

```
  - name: "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:${_KANIKO_VERSION}"
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        /kaniko/executor --dockerfile=path/to/Dockerfile --cache=true  --use-new-run --destination=${_EXTRACT_IMAGE} --cache-repo=${_EXTRACT_IMAGE}/cache

substitutions:
  _KANIKO_VERSION: "v1.9.0"
  _EXTRACT_IMAGE: "europe-docker.pkg.dev/<ProjectID>/extract"
```